# In Tao's proof of Hölder’s inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> (Hölder’s inequality) Let $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$ for some $0 < p,q \leq \infty$. Then $fg \in L^r$ and $\|fg\|_{L^r} \leq \|f\|_{L^p} \|g\|_{L^q}$, where the exponent $r$ is defined by the formula $\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}$.

In his lecture [note](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/245b-notes-3-lp-spaces/), Tao reduces the problem to the nontrivial essential case where $p,q<\infty$, $r=1$, and  $\|f\|_{L^p}=\|g\|_{L^q} = 1$. The following is his proof:

> Our task is now to show that
>   $$\int_X |fg|\ d\mu \leq 1. \tag{*}$$
>
> Here, we use the convexity of the exponential function $t \mapsto e^t$ on ${}[0,+\infty)$, which implies the convexity of the function $t \mapsto |f(x)|^{p(1-t)} |g(x)|^{qt}$ for $t \in [0,1]$ for any $x$. In particular we have
>   $$
> |f(x) g(x)| \leq \frac{1}{p} |f(x)|^p + \frac{1}{q} |g(x)|^q \tag{**}
> $$
>   and the claim $(*)$ follows from the normalisations on $p, q, f, g.$

Here are my **questions**:

- How is the convexity of the function $t \mapsto |f(x)|^{p(1-t)} |g(x)|^{qt}$ for $t \in [0,1]$ for any $x$ built up?
- How is the convexity used to get $(**)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is routine execrise to show that
$$
t\rightarrow e^{t}
$$
is a convex function by checking second derivative. Now define the function (for fixed $x)$
$$
t\rightarrow p(1-t)\log(|f(x)|)+qt\log(|g(x)|)\rightarrow e^{p(1-t)\log(|f(x)|)+qt\log(|g(x)|)}
$$
and it is the composition of a linear function with a convex function. Thus it must be convex as well.

To get the desired inequality, now it suffice to set $t=\frac{1}{q}$. Recall that $p,q$ are Holder conjugates, so you have $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Recall that a function is convex implies $$F(t)\le (1-t)*F(0)+tF(1)$$ 
Thus setting $t=1/q$ we have 
$$
|f(x)g(x)|\le 1/q*|g(x)|^{q}+\frac{1}{p}*|f(x)|^{p}
$$
and we recover the original inequality. Here 
$$
t=1/q,F=e^{p(1-t)\log(|f(x)|)+qt\log(|g(x)|)}, t\in [0,1]
$$

As a side remark, it is well known that Holder's inequality can be viewed as a form Jensen's inequality, but Tao's proof is still very nice for pedalogical purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand what you mean by setting $t=1/p$. What is the convex combination to get $(**)$?

Comment: Fixed the typo - hope it helps!

Comment: @Jack: Is it clear to you now?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still don't see where the convexity of the map $
t\mapsto|f(x)|^{p(1-t)}|g(x)|^{qt}$ is used. I believe only the convexity of the exponential map is needed in order to get $(**)$ and I just wrote up an answer.

Comment: @Jack: I updated, hopefully it helps. To see how the convexity of the map is directly being used, recall that any time convexity means the value in the middle is less than the linear combination at the end points. In particular for $f$ defined on $[0,1]$, we have $f(x)\le xf(0)+(1-x)f(1)$. Here the end points are $0,1$ and the value at the middle is $x=1/q$. Thus you just need to plug in to get the formula.

Comment: You mean $f(x)\leq xf(1)+(1-x)f(0)$?

Comment: @Jack: Yes you are right - I should be more careful with constants!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Tao's proof but here's the proof of Holder's inequality I know in the non-trivial case. It does not constitute a proper answer to your question but I believe it can highlight the use of convexity of $\exp(\cdot)$.

> Set $$ F := \frac{|f|}{\|f\|}~~~~~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~~~~~ G :=
>  \frac{|g|}{\|g\|}.$$ You can easily check that $$ \int_X F^p \; d\mu ~=~
>  \int_X G^q \; d\mu ~=~ 1.$$ If $x \in X$ is such that $0 < F(x), G(x)
>  < \infty$, then there exists numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $$ F(x) =
>  \exp\left(\frac{s}{p}\right)~~~~~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~~~~~ G(x) = \exp\left(\frac{t}{q}\right).$$
>   Since $p$ and $q$ are conjugate exponents, the convexity of
>   $\exp(\cdot)$ gives $$ F(x)G(x) ~=~ 
>  \exp\left( \frac{1}{p} s + \frac{1}{q} t\right) \\=~ \exp\left(
>  \frac{1}{p} s + \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) t\right) \\\leq~
>  \frac{1}{p}\exp(s) + \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) \exp(t) \\=~ 
>  \frac{1}{p}\exp(s) +  \frac{1}{q} \exp(t)  \\=~ \frac{1}{p}F(x)^p + \frac{1}{q}G(x)^q$$ for all $x
>  \in X$. Now integrate over $X$ to get $$ \int_X FG\; d\mu ~\leq~
>  \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} ~=~ 1$$ and finaly $$\int_X |fg| \; d\mu
>  ~\leq~ \left(\int_X |f|^p\; d\mu\right)^\frac{1}{p}\left(\int_X |g|^q \;
>  d\mu\right)^\frac{1}{q}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=|f(x)|$ and $B=|g(x)|$. 
I just found that one does not need the convexity of the map
$$
t\mapsto A^{p(1-t)}B^{qt}
$$
and thus
the first question is unnecessary. By the convexity of the exponential function, 
$$
A^{p(1-t)}B^{qt}=\exp[(1-t)p\log A+tq\log B]
\leq (1-t)A^p+tB^q
$$
for all $t\in[0,1]$. Now one can choose the right $t\in[0,1]$ to get $(**)$.